# PrimeFaces barChart is not shown

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

I have a problem with barCharts.
I wrote an example for barCharts from Primefaces but on the page they are not visible.

Here the Bean class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

public class InvoiceStatisticsBean implements Serializable {
private CartesianChartModel categoryModel; 

public InvoiceStatisticsBean() {
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();  

    ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();  
    boys.setLabel("Boys");  

    boys.set("2004", 120);  
    boys.set("2005", 100);  
    boys.set("2006", 44);  
    boys.set("2007", 150);  
    boys.set("2008", 25);  

    ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();  
    girls.setLabel("Girls");  

    girls.set("2004", 52);  
    girls.set("2005", 60);  
    girls.set("2006", 110);  
    girls.set("2007", 135);  
    girls.set("2008", 120);  

    categoryModel.addSeries(boys);  
    categoryModel.addSeries(girls); 
}

public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel() {
    return categoryModel;
}

public void setCategoryModel(CartesianChartModel categoryModel) {
    this.categoryModel = categoryModel;
}
}
```

And here is the .xhtml file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Invoice Statistics</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="header">
                <h1>Invoice Statistics</h1>
            </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <p>There should be a barChart</p>   
            <p:barChart id="horizontal" value="#{invoiceStatisticsBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="se" style="height:300px" title="Horizontal Bar Chart" orientation="horizontal" min="0" max="200"/>  
            <p:outputPanel>test</p:outputPanel>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the bad editing but this is my first question here.

So if i then start the .xhtml page, the space for the barChart is reserved on the page but it is nothing shown.

Can anyone help me please with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <p:panel>
       <p:chart ......>
 </p:panel>
```

that should fix it, p:panel

Answer (score 0):

ok primefaces 4.0 was the problem.

Swapped the jquery.js file from primefaces 4.0 with the one from 3.5

Answer (score 0):

if you use a template using jquery so you should add this line

$.noConflict();

Comment: <script> $.noConflict(); </script>